# Doing arithmetic and passing it to the next command

Tags: windows, command-line, stdout

I know how to do this in /bin/sh, but I'm struggling a bit in Windows.

I know you can do arithmetic on 32-bit signed integers with

```
SET /a 2+2
4
```

But how do I pass this to the next command? For example, the process I want to perform is as follows.

Consumer editions of Windows have no native automated sleep function (I believe?) -- the best way to perform a sleep is to use `PING` in association with the `-n` switch to get that many seconds, minus one, of sleep. The following command is effective for a silent sleep:

```
PING localhost -n 3 > NUL
```

But I want to alias this into a sleep command. I'd like to have it elegant so that you enter the actual number of seconds you want to sleep after the command, right now I can do

```
DOSKEY SLEEP=PING 127.0.0.1 -n $1 > NUL
```

Which works, but it's always 1 second less than your input, so if you wanted to sleep for one second you would have to use the command `SLEEP 2`. That's not exactly ideal.

Is there some way for me to pass the arithmetic of `$1+1` and pass it on to the next command in Windows? I assume there is some way of using STDOUT...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
DOSKEY SLEEP==set /a t=$1+1 $G NULL $T PING 127.0.0.1 -n %t% $G NULL
```

The `$T` is a command separator equivalent to `&`.

Note that the `> NUL` redirects the output of `DOSKEY` rather than the macro. You can see that it's not included if you do `DOSKEY /MACROS`. To do the redirection that you want, append `$G NUL` to the end of the line as shown above.

Something like this will also work:

```
DOSKEY SLEEP=for /f %t in ('set /a $1+1') do @PING 127.0.0.1 -n %t $G NUL
```

Try both and see which one works better for you.

Comment: That's absolutely perfect. Wow, I didn't realise the Windows command line would be this bad. :D

Comment: beautiful i must say

Comment: +1. This is why real hackers love .bat files: There's nothing more hacky!

Answer (score 1):

1. As far as I know cmd.exe does not offer readily available function for in-execution evaluation of function.
2. If you just wanted to wait for 1 more second, just insert another ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 into it.
3. You can consider installation of sleep command from the [windows server administration tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c16ae515-c8f4-47ef-a1e4-a8dcbacff8e3&displaylang=en).
4. How about an installation of cygwin/powershell?

EDIT: correct my ping parameter stupidity

Comment: Not possible, this needs to be deployed to clients without cygwin/powershell and needs to be standalone as a batch file. Another `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1` as it executes and terminates nearly instantaneously.

Comment: should have been another "ping -n 2 127.0.0.1" sorry my gross stupidity. should have taken the clue that ping -n [k] 127.0.0.1 will wait for k-1 seconds...

Comment: Hm, I suppose that's a possibility, but not really an elegant one (not that this is going to be elegant anyway... Windows command line never is).